# BLE and Bluetooth limitations

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am looking for some help connected to `BLE` and `Bluetooth` on `Android`. I would appreciate some help with the following questions:

- In the case of `BLE`, is the `CI` (Connection Interval) and `MTU` (Maximum Transfer Unit) re-negotiated when the phone goes to standby?
- In case of `BLE`, what is the fastest `CI` (Connection Interval) supported by `Android`? Has this changed between `Android` version 5.0 and 10.0?
- In case of `Bluetooth` Classic and `SPP` protocol, can the accessory always wake up an app residing in the background? If not - when is this not possible?

I tried finding an official `Google` support channel, but I haven’t found any in this area. If you know of any other place I can get help with this topic, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1. No.
2. 11.25 ms since Android 6. Previously it was 7.5 ms.
3. Don't know.